# Unable to reset OpenLiteSpeed WebAdmin Console password

Tags: litespeed

I've made multiple attempts via both `/usr/local/lsws/admin/misc/admpass.sh` and `/usr/local/lsws/admin/misc/lsup.sh -a`, always receiving the confirmation:

> Administrator's username/password is updated successfully!

But attempting to log in produces an error:

> Invalid credentials.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening up the access rights to htpasswd, e.g.

```
chmod 644 /usr/local/lsws/admin/conf/htpasswd
```

I had the same problem with a recent install. Check your server error log? Mine revealed a permission problem:

```
[NOTICE] [(serverip):51533:HTTP2-45#_AdminVHost] [STDERR] PHP Warning:  fopen(/usr/local/lsws/admin/conf/htpasswd): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /usr/local/lsws/admin/html.open/lib/CAuthorizer.php on line 227
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if your password is updated on file here, make sure it shows different string every time you run the "admpass.sh" script.

```
cat /usr/local/lsws/admin/conf/htpasswd
```

Can you also share how you install the openlitespeed and which version?

Best

Comment: Yes, the the hash changes after running. I'm running [openlitespeed-wordpress](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/gc-image-pub/openlitespeed-wordpress) on GCE

Comment: Just launched a new one (openlitespeed wordpress) on zone us-west4-c, and I can change the password multiple times without any issue. Please raise a ticket to bug@litespeedtech.com If you can reproduce it on new server with this post appended. Thanks.